# iPad simulators not rotated if I try to rotate it programatically

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have tried to rotate the simulators programatically in Xamarin.iOS as like  in the below code snippet,

```
public void ChangeOrientation(string mode)
{
    // Need to rotate the device to the landscape mode.
    if (mode == "Landscape")
    {
        UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight), new NSString("orientation"));
    }
    else
    {
        // Need to rotate the device to the potrait mode.
        UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait), new NSString("orientation"));
    }
}
```

If I call the above method, the simulator should rotate. Actually, iPhone simulators are rotated. But iPad simulators are not rotated. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Divakar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to working sample app https://github.com/ramyareddyn/RotationSample

Hope it helps!